Flutter error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
`Launching lib/flavors/main_dev.dart on sdk gphone arm64 in debug mode...
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':google_sign_in_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/yurtaslanmac/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/yurtaslanmac/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/75ce9466628e968a28c2d9274c899d53/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/yurtaslanmac/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/75ce9466628e968a28c2d9274c899d53/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Error: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).
`
I encountered this problem after updating android studio. None of my apps build in android studio.
flutter doctor --verbose
`[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 15.0.1 24A348 darwin-arm64, locale en-TR)
• Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at /Users/yurtaslanmac/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 2663184aa7 (4 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
• Engine revision 36335019a8
• Dart version 3.5.3
• DevTools version 2.37.3
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/yurtaslanmac/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11)
• All Android licenses accepted.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.0)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 16A242d
• CocoaPods version 1.15.2
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.90.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.98.0
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
• sdk gphone arm64 (mobile)       • emulator-5554         • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
• macOS (desktop)                 • macos                 • darwin-arm64   • macOS 15.0.1 24A348 darwin-arm64
• Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad • darwin         • macOS 15.0.1 24A348 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)                    • chrome                • web-javascript • Google Chrome 129.0.6668.90
[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
• No issues found!`
How can I fix this problem and build all my apps? Can you please help?

This error is common when the Flutter package is not compatible with Java.
/Users/yurtaslanmac/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/75ce9466628e968a28c2d9274c899d53/

/Users/yurtaslanmac/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/75ce9466628e968a28c2d9274c899d53/

you can go to this file path  C:/Users/yurtaslanmac/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ and search both  id 75ce9466628e968a28c2d9274c899d53 and 75ce9466628e968a28c2d9274c899d53 Delete both file than again build.

"I tried this, but the problem couldn't be solved."

What error is showing after implementation?

I solved a similar problem with opening the project's android folder as a separate project in Android Studio (Android Studio top left panel -> Open -> android folder in your project -> Click OK), which then prompted me to use the built-in upgrade manager. With that, I upgraded to the latest version of Gradle, and my flutter app was working again.
